# Override a Material UI style without using an HOC?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

Is there any way to override a Material UI components styling without having to create a whole new component using `withStyles()`?

For instance, say I am rendering the following and I just want to change the color of the "Delete" label:

```
<div style={styles.rowFooter}>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={<ClearIcon />}
    label="Clear"
    title="Clear all fields."
    onClick={clearFields}
  />
  <FormControlLabel
    control={<DeleteIcon />}
    label="Delete"
    title="Delete this row."
    onClick={deleteRow}
  />
</div>
```

To do this, I'd usually have to:

- Create a new styles function that returns `{ color: "maroon" }`.
- Create a new component to render the "Delete" button.
- Wrap my new component `withStyles(newStylesFn)(MyComponent)`.

But I don't want to do all of that. Is there any way to avoid it?

**Update:**

One way that I know of is to just pass a CSS `className`. I was looking for something besides that because it doesn't even work in this situation to override the nested element.

What I'd really like to be able to do is just pass `style={{ color: "maroon" }}`, but that only changes the color of the icon, not the actual label text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **classes** prop to override styles provided by Material UI instead of **className**.

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={<DeleteIcon />}
  label="Delete"
  title="Delete this row."
  classes={{
    label: 'labelStyle'
  }}
/>
```

styles.css

```
.labelStyle {
  color: maroon !important;
}
```

Although it's Not the perfect solution, it still does the job without using withStyles().

Comment: Thank you very much @Yakov-Kiszner. I couldn't find any mention of this in the docs. If anyone knows where it is, please add to this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also relevant - prior to this solution, I attempted using regular CSS and I read about how you can change the JSS insertion point, so you don't have to use `!important`. [CSS Injection order](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order)

Comment: Looks like the docs encourages to use CSS-in-JS by using the JSS library. You can find out more at [A Journey toward better style](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/a-journey-toward-better-style). However, the docs also show you how to use classes with JSS (not CSS). [Overriding with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes)

Comment: I had read both of those, thanks. CSS Modules with CSS Variables are the future IMO and I'm going to avoid JSS and other CSS-in-JS kits where possible.